# Accessing website on old server with cPanel

Tags: networking, ip, hosting, cpanel, web-hosting

We have a new website and it'll be using new server. We'd like the domain to point to new server but also want to keep the old website running and access it for internal purpose.

I tried oldserveripaddress/~ftpusername but this did not work.

How do we go about this? Both old and new servers are cPanel.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the old web server is still answering to the domain name.

set up a entry in your host file (on your pc) to point your website at the old IP address
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx www.yourwebsite.com

then you should be able to access the old site, just comment it out after when you want to access the new one.